# Find a most common class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry for the format of this question. I know should include some code, but i don't even know where to start.
I need to find the most common class among divs with another class, containing a certain symbol. The problem is to find the most common one.

Let's say there is a number of divs

```
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass1"></div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass3"></div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-2 subclass3"></div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass2"></div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass1"></div>
```

How do i find the total number of subclass-1 (in this case?). Classes are generated dynamically, and i never know which one is gonna be the most common each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the complete list of class with their count from the following code..

```
var classes = new Object();

$("*").each(function() {
    if (this.className.length > 0)
    {
        var arrTmp = this.className.split(" ");
        for (var i=0; i<arrTmp.length; i++)
        {
            if ($.trim(arrTmp[i]).length > 0)
            {
                if (classes[arrTmp[i]])
                    classes[arrTmp[i]] = classes[arrTmp[i]] + 1;
                else
                    classes[arrTmp[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }    
});

var sortable = [];
for (var arr in classes)
      sortable.push([arr, classes[arr]])
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return b[1] - a[1]});

alert(sortable);
```

Test on JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qsfdm286/

Comment: most of the solutions posted above are for specific class or specific section .. the code I posted is for general purpose.. you can just change the selector in the first line and it will than target only specific areas in your html..

Comment: this is awesome! though, how do i separate the most common one, .mainclass aside? (i'm pretty new to js)

Comment: it's already sorted by number in descending order.. so you can access most common classes by sortable[0], sortable[1], sortable[2] and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
var counter = {}, //to store the count of occurences temporarely
max; //the most common class
//iterate over te main class
$('.mainclass').each(function () {
    //find the subclass-* value
    var cs = this.className.match(/subclass-\d+/)[0];
    counter[cs] = counter[cs] || 0;
    //increment the count of occurrence
    counter[cs]++;
    if (counter[cs] > (counter[max] || 0)) {
        //if the current one is more then change the max to current class
        max = cs;
    }
});
console.log(max)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k709405s/)

---

If you want to consider `subclass1` also then

```
var counter = {}, //to store the count of occurences temporarely
max; //the most common class
//iterate over te main class
$('.mainclass').each(function () {
    //find the subclass-* value
    var parts = this.className.match(/subclass-?\d+/g);
    $.each(parts, function (i, cs) {
        counter[cs] = counter[cs] || 0;
        //increment the count of occurrence
        counter[cs]++;
        if (counter[cs] > (counter[max] || 0)) {
            //if the current one is more then change the max to current class
            max = cs;
        }
    })
});
console.log(max, counter)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k709405s/2/)

Comment: when for test purposes, i try to alert the counter var, it gives me object Object

Comment: That's because that's what it is - an object. If you want to output it to human-readable text using `console.log()` use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: You need to alert the value of `max`... the value is already logged to the browser console... check the browser console to see those

Answer (score 0):

You can find usage of the class in following way when you know the class

```
var classList = document.getElementById('divId').className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
   var numItems = $('.'+classList[i]).length;
   console.log('Usage of class '  classList[i] 'is ' numItems ) 
}
```

Comment: i don't know the class. that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.length()` function and then bubble sort the results

```
var numberOfSubClasses = 3
var mostCommonQuant = null;
var mostCommonRef = null;
for(var count =1; count <= numberOfSubClasses; count++)
{
    var ptr = $(".mainclass .subclass-1 .subclass"+count).length;
    if(ptr > mostCommonQuant)
        mostCommonRef = ptr;

}
console.log(mostCommonRef);
```

Comment: as i mentioned in the post, classes are generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that takes a NodeList (or HTMLCollection) and returns the most common class. You can run this snippet and see the console output.

Here's the specific parts of JavaScript that I take advantage of for this solution.

***Object as associative array***

In JavaScript, objects are hash tables, and I exploit that property of them to store the classes encountered as keys, and the count of encounters as the values.

***Object properties given by variables***

In JavaScript, you can add properties to objects from a variable. These two examples are semantically identical:

```
var propName = 'age', 
    obj = {}; 
obj[propName] = 18;  // obj.age === 18
```

and

```
var obj = {}; 
obj.age = 18;
```

***Immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)***

Say I have some throwaway code that I'll use once, and it might be useful to encapsulate in a function. I usually use this to avoid cluttering up the function namespace with temporary variables (otherwise, I need to keep track of them). `mostCommonClass()` returns the result of invoking the function:

```
function() {
    var maximumName = '',
        maximumValue = 0,
        keys = Object.keys(pairs);

    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (pairs[key] > maximumValue) { 
        maximumName = key; 
        maximumValue = pairs[key]; 
      }
    });
    return maximumName; 
};
```

It does that by wrapping the function body in an invocation express. Here's an example without the function body to make it more clear.

```
return (function() { /* do stuff */ } ());
```

Wrapping the entire function in parentheses is one way of making the syntax here correct, and the `()` at the end invokes the function just declared.

```js
function mostCommonClass(list, omit) { 
  var pairs = {}; 
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var classes = list.item(i).classList; 
    for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) { 
      if (pairs[classes[j]]) { 
        pairs[classes[j]]++; 
      } else {
        pairs[classes[j]] = 1; 
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (omit) {
    omit.forEach(function(el) { 
      delete pairs[el];
    }); 
  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(pairs)); 

  return (function() {
    var maximumName = '',
        maximumValue = 0,
        keys = Object.keys(pairs);
    
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (pairs[key] > maximumValue) { 
        maximumName = key; 
        maximumValue = pairs[key]; 
      }
    });
    return maximumName; 
  }()); 
}

console.log(
  mostCommonClass(document.getElementsByClassName('mainclass'), ['mainclass'])
);
```

```html
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass1">1</div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass3">2</div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-2 subclass3">3</div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass2">4</div>
<div class="mainclass subclass-1 subclass1">5</div>
```

Comment: i'm pretty new to js. i'm guessing var pairs is supposed to return the most common class. am i right?

Comment: @Arazam I am using pairs (a plain JS object) as an associative array.

Comment: @Arazam I added a log call that demonstrates what `pairs` is.

Comment: how do i turn it into var though (i'm really really new to js :) )

Comment: @Arazam Sorry I'm not following. What is returned from `mostCommonClass()` is the name of the most common class as a string.

Comment: for the end result, i'm trying to compare a few urls to the most common class. let's say if ($('.watever a').attr('href').contains(mostcommonclass)) { do such and such }